# Floating images using LightBox 2.6

Tags: html, css, lightbox

By the look of the posts here I'm in the deep end with the big boys whereas I need the toddlers paddling pool. So apologies if I'm in the wrong place with my basic problem.

I can't get images to float with LightBox [v. 2.6]

I have a sample problem page here - http://quivis.co.uk/PROBLEMS/lightbox-float/index.html

That page has 2 copies of the same image. Both 'work' in the sense that when you click them LightBox does its brilliant thing and fires up correctly, but both image links display incorrectly.

1. The top image looks as it should i.e. with mouse-over highlights/border colours etc but will not float right. In some browsers there is also a large redundant area to the left that I am unable to remove.
2. The bottom image floats as I want it to but in the process the image link styling is lost.

As all things are possible it must be possible to combine the look of 1 with the positioning of 2 but I can't see how to do it!

All the related files are within the 'PROBLEMS' folder. Please let me know if I should paste the html or css here.

Any help much appreciated.  Thanks, Duncan

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: The first image _does_ float right, but you don’t see any effect of this because it floats within the A element around it which has `display:inline-block` set (through `.lightbox-image-link`). Float the links containing the images, instead of the images themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the post zey. What code; the css or html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set float:right style to a tag instead of float:right to images.
And there is mis-spelling of class attribute in second a tag, it is mentioned as 'xclass', correct that spelling too.

Comment: Thanks Khurram. I'll try floating a tag. The 'misspelling' is deliberate; I had to turn the class 'off' in order to get the image to float right for purpose of this post.